# Determine whether a string contains any of a set of strings

Tags: ruby, string

I'm using `Mechanize` to interact with a few web pages, and I'm trying to determine whether a given form submission resulted in an error.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
agent.page.body.include?("I'm an error message!")
```

But I just discovered *another* error message. Since I don't want to do:

```
agent.page.body.include?("I'm an error message!") || agent.page.body.include?("Another error message")
```

How can I determine whether the page body contains *either* error message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
error_messages.any? { |mes| agent.page.body.include? mes }
```

Comment: With, of course: `error_messages = ["I'm an error message!", "Another error message"]`

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, do it in one Regex pass:

```
error_messages = /I'm an error message!|Another error message/
if agent.page.body =~ error_messages
  ...
end
```

You'll need to ensure that you escape any error messages that contain special regex characters. To make it maintainable:

```
if agent.page.body =~ Regexp.union("foo", "bar", "jim.bob", "jam|jam")
  ...
end
```

You should only use this if **you have tested** and found the speed of Nakilon's answer is not enough, however. :)

Comment: And too lazy to write solution with regexes escaping ))) +1

Comment: Simplifying out the regex escaping:  `Regexp.union(*error_messages)` from the comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215590/check-if-string-contains-any-substring-in-an-array-in-ruby#comment13121626_10215848